System.Security.AccessControl AccessControlType vs AceType
Is System.Security.AccessControl.AceType is just more detailed version of System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType? Is there a way to convert AceType to AccessControlType or these are two different things?

Although both the enums looks similar there is bit difference in the way they are defined. As per Microsoft docs.
Purpose :
"AccessControlType" : Specifies whether ACE allows or denies the access.
"AceType" : Specifies the type of ACE access. That has many values defined here. We can also take this as the detailed version of AccessControlType.
Convertions : Direct conversion isn't possible as they represent different things, but you can consider writing new converter using the Allowed / Denied Keywords

and what about "AceQualifier"?

AceQualifier is used to define the  purpose of an ACE, which contains the kind of action that ACE performs .
Where as AceType provides Detailed classification of ACE (different access levels)
and AccessControlType provides basic information about the access ( allowed/ denied)
